# How to move div in DOM to last empty position

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I got a image upload script which shows Thumbnails of images.
I got a div tag for each slot and want to delete a img by click.
now I tried a sort algorithm which sorts the changed divs but he always has 2 divs with same id.
here is what I tried...

My HTML looks like

```js
function rut(id) {
  // uploaded number
  var lmax = $('#max').val();
  lmax = Number(lmax);
  for (i = 1; i < 19; i++) {

    if (i > id && i != lmax) {
      var esf = Number($('#sell_div_' + i).attr("data-id"));
      var es = esf;
      esf--;
      if (esf < 10) {
        esf = "0" + esf;
      }
      $('#sell_div_' + i).attr("data-id", esf);

    } else if (i == id) {
      if (lmax < 10) {
        lmax = "0" + (Number(lmax));
      }
      var ix = (i);
      var llmax = (lmax - 1);
      var lllmax = 'xx';
      ix = (ix < 10 ? "0" + ix : ix);
      llmax = (llmax < 10 ? "0" + llmax : llmax);
      $('#sell_div_' + lmax).attr("data-id", llmax);
      $('#sell_div_' + i).attr("data-id", lmax);


    }
  }
  var $people = $('#imag_container'),
    $peopleli = $people.children('div');

  $peopleli.sort(function(a, b) {
    var an = a.getAttribute('data-id'),
      bn = b.getAttribute('data-id');

    if (an > bn) {
      return 1;
    }
    if (an < bn) {
      return -1;
    }
    return 0;
  });
  $peopleli.detach().appendTo($people);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-id='01' id='sell_div_1'>[img1]</div>
<div data-id='02' id='sell_div_2'>[img2]</div>
<div data-id='03' id='sell_div_3'>[img3]</div>
<div data-id='04' id='sell_div_4'>[img4]</div>
<div data-id='05' id='sell_div_5'>[img5]</div>
<div data-id='06' id='sell_div_6'>[img6]</div>
<div data-id='07' id='sell_div_7'>[img7]</div>
<div data-id='08' id='sell_div_8'>[img8]</div>
```

and I want that he is moving img2 to position 4 and position 4 to 3, and 3 to 2 and 2 to 1
after this I can hide the image

id = deleted img id e.g. 2

Comment: IF you delete (like you say) ID 2 why should than some 2 move to 4?... Aren't you overcomplicating your task? What are you actually building? What is the final expected result and why? By Why I mean, why do you need IDs at all? Why sorting? Detach? Why detaching? In HTML if you remove an element all the other ones will fall in place... $peopleli? What is peopleli? Can you create a [mcve]?

Comment: frankly, I think your problem starts here `function rut(id)`

Comment: I've added a Stack Snippet of your code, but it does nothing right now, since nothing calls the `rut` function (also, the code refers to a number of elements which don't exist in the HTML provided).